# How to set --data-binary and --compressed in Curb gem

Tags: ruby, curb

I'd like to set --data-binary and --compressed options.
In curl:

```
curl 'http://test.url' --data-binary test_json --compressed
```

How do I set --data-binary and --compressed options in curb?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
ce = Curl::Easy.new("http://test.url")
ce.encoding = 'gzip'
ce.multipart_form_post = true
fields = [
  Curl::PostField.file('foo', foo_file_path),
  Curl::PostField.file('bar', bar_file_path)
]
curl.http_post(fields)
ce.perform
```

the response body is in `ce.body_str`